# How to have a two-column table of contents with a centered header?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing a D&D-style roleplaying game in LaTeX, and I'm a bit stuck on the formatting. I'd like to have a two-column table of contents, which is simple enough:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
```

However, this produces the toc header in the first column (as expected):
[image]

I can use `\renewcommand*\contentsname{}` to remove the header altogether and then add it back manually, but the empty header still occupies space:
[image]

Is there any way to get rid of that empty space?

Comment: perhaps `\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}` and then ` \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\end{multicols}}` at the end. If you're not sure where to put these, it is one of the *many* reasons why we ask for [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `titlesec` package to "format" the table of contents name to get rid of the default spaces before and after.

I guessed you are using a book or report class, so I aimed to the section command  `\chapter`.

The  command `\setupTOC` allows to apply the fix only to the table of contents.

You might have to modify the space before and after according your specific setup for the chapter title.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{}

%************************************* added
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\setupTOC}{%
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{} 

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}
{*7} %  % vertical space before the title <<<<<<<<<<
{*-15}  %  idem after title (in ex units + glue) <<<<<<<<<<<
}
%*************************************

\begin{document}    
    
\begin{center}  
{\Large \bfseries TABLE OF CONTENTS\bigskip}    
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
{\setupTOC  \tableofcontents}
\end{multicols}

\chapter{One}
    \section{Section one}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \section{Section two}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \subsection{Subsection three}
    \subsection{Subsection four}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    
    \chapter{Two}
    \section{Section one}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \section{Section two}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \subsection{Subsection three}
    \subsection{Subsection four}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    
    \chapter{Three}
    \section{Section one}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \section{Section two}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    \subsection{Subsection three}
    \subsection{Subsection four}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}
    \subsection{Subsection one}
    \subsection{Subsection two}
    
\end{document}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `\tableofcontents` depends on the document class.  This only works for article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\contentsname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{test}

\section{another test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 As a matter of fact also works for chapters.  `\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
 \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{multicols}{2}%
   \@starttoc{toc}%
  \end{multicols}
 }
 \makeatother`